# Gnome-terminal prompt does not clear up fully

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, bashrc, prompt

I am running **ubuntu 16.04 LTS** and **gnome-terminal** within **unity**.

Sometimes when I clear my terminal the command line isn't cleared up fully. Some bit of the command left and I can't remove them. I think it might be because of my prompt customization.

Here's an extract of the `.bashrc` file which I suspect to cause the problem:

```
## Prompt Configuration

# Colors
bold=$(tput bold)
normal=$(tput sgr0)
orange="$(echo -e "\e[38;2;255;102;0m")"
blue="$(echo -e "\033[34m")"
pink="$(echo -e "\033[31m")"
white="$(echo -e "\033[00m")"

# Add git branch if its present to PS1
parse_git_branch() {
 git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}${bold}${orange}\u:${blue}\w${pink} $(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n${orange}➜ ${white}'

else
    #PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u:\w $(parse_git_branch)\n\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Comment: Did u try ctrl+L

Comment: Yes that's when I do ctrl+L that sometimes, I still do have some part of the previous command that I can't delete

Comment: Nit 1: There's no need to execute an `echo` on a string constant and use command substitution to catch its output; it's too complicated. You can assign the desired value straight to the variable, e.g. by `blue=$'\e[34m'`.

Comment: Nit 2: The value you assign to the variable `white` does not set white, it sets the terminal's default colors and attributes, whatever they are.

Comment: I'm glad to see people use true colors :) Just for reference, your choice of orange is very close to color #202 of the 256-color palette (that one is exactly RGB 255;95;0), so you can switch to `\e[38;5;202m` if you ever plan to use a terminal that does not support true colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-printable characters, e.g. color changing and boldness changing escape sequences need to be enclosed between `\[` and `\]` in PS1. See `man bash`, section "PROMPTING".